# jquery drog drop order for three level

Tags: jquery

How can i get child level li to dragdrop? its working for me but the second level order does not save in database table,

this is my javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function(){     
          function slideout(){
      setTimeout(function(){
      $("#response").slideUp("slow", function () {
          });

    }, 2000);}

        $("#response").hide();
        $(function() {
            $("ul.main, ul.child").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update'; 
                $.post("", order, function(theResponse){
                    $("#response").html("Order Saved");
                    $("#response").slideDown('slow');
                    slideout();
                });                                                              
            }

        });


        });

    }); 

<ul class="main">
    <li><span id="arrayorder_1">item1
       <ul class="child">
           <li><span id="arrayorder_2">item2</li>
           <li><span id="arrayorder_3">item3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span id="arrayorder_4">item4</li>
</ul>
```

the reorder javascript is working but the child data not saving in to db..

this is order php code

```
$child  = $_POST['arrayorder'];


    if ($_POST['update'] == "update"){

        $count = 1;
        foreach ($array as $idval) {
          MyModel::newInstance()->updateMenuItemOrder( $idval, $count); 
            $count ++;  
        }

    }
```

main order saved correctly but child order dosn't 
how can i save the child  data to data table